# How to get from Nagoya Airport to Matsumoto by bus

Tags: public-transport, japan, buses, nagoya, ngo

I will be arriving at [Chubu Centrair International Airport](http://wikitravel.org/en/Chubu_Centrair_International_Airport) (Nagoya Airport) and I would like to take a bus to Matsumoto, Nagano Prefecture, Japan.

I have seen these pages:

- http://www.centrair.jp/en/to_and_from/access/bus.html
- http://welcome.city.matsumoto.nagano.jp/contents01+index.id+2.htm

But I couldn't figure out how it works. I guess my biggest question is how to get from the airport to the bus station that has buses going to Matsumoto. I would prefer not to take a taxi there.

Comment: You can take the bus from the airport to Nagoya station. From there you can take a train or bus to Matsumoto. I would go by train myself. You can check these websites for more info. - [Hyperdia Search](http://www.hyperdia.com/cgi/en/search.html?dep_node=NAGOYA&arv_node=MATSUMOTO&via_node01=&via_node02=&via_node03=&year=2016&month=01&day=04&hour=23&minute=00&search_type=0&search_way=&transtime=undefined&sort=0&max_route=5&faretype=0&ship=off&lmlimit=null&search_target=route&facility=reserved&sum_target=7) and [Meitetsu Bus](http://www.meitetsu-bus.co.jp/english/).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to take the bus? JR has regular direct Nagoya-Matsumoto trains that cover the distance in 2 hours.

Comment: @jpatokal, It was my understanding that the bus is the cheapest option since I was on a tight budget. I ended up taking the train, though, because someone met me in Nagoya and they were taking the train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buses from Nagoya to Matsumoto depart from Meitetsu Bus Center ([Google Maps](https://www.google.co.jp/maps/place/%E5%90%8D%E9%89%84%E3%83%90%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%EF%BC%88%E3%83%90%E3%82%B9%EF%BC%89/@35.168214,136.8811063,16.24z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x600376de0ee26a41:0x1d6f1c1146a89b8c)). The easiest way to get there from Chubu Airport is to take a Meitetsu train, which will bring you to Meitetsu-Nagoya station, right next to the bus center, but there is also a bus from the airport to the bus center (abbreviated "B.C." on the airport transportation page you linked). For both the train and the buses, English guidance will be available for ticket purchase, etc. (Meitetsu is the name of the train and bus company, by the way.)